# add CSS class to rows that starts with capital letter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am newbie in Javascript and Jquery. I want to add CSS class via Jquery to rows that starts with capital letter. HTML code is generated automatically by Django Admin. For instance this row:

```
<tr class="row1"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3641" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3641/">Ramës Mapo ---&gt; </a></th></tr>
```

must have red background color.

Here is my source code but it does not works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


    <style>
important {background-color:red}'
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var t = document.getElementsByClassName("field-__str__").textContent;
        //alert(t);
        if(t.charAt(0) === t.charAt(0).toUpperCase())
        {
            $("field-__str__ tr th a").addClass("important");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="result_list">
<thead>
<tr>

<th scope="col"  class="action-checkbox-column">

   <div class="text"><span><input type="checkbox" id="action-toggle" /></span></div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</th>
<th scope="col"  class="column-__str__">

   <div class="text"><span>Bigram</span></div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>


<tr class="row1"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3641" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3641/">Ramës Mapo ---&gt; </a></th></tr>


<tr class="row2"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3640" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3640/">Edi Ramës ---&gt; </a></th></tr>

<tr class="row2"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3554" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3554/">përmbysi lulishten ---&gt; </a></th></tr>


<tr class="row1"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3553" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3553/">bredhat përmbysi ---&gt; </a></th></tr>


<tr class="row2"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3552" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3552/">preu bredhat ---&gt; </a></th></tr>


<tr class="row1"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3551" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3551/">tregon preu ---&gt; </a></th></tr>


<tr class="row2"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3550" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3550/">sheshit tregon ---&gt; </a></th></tr>


<tr class="row1"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3549" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3549/">gjelbërim sheshit ---&gt; </a></th></tr>


<tr class="row2"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3548" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3548/">Flet gjelbërim ---&gt; </a></th></tr>


<tr class="row1"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3547" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3547/">bashkie Flet ---&gt; </a></th></tr>


<tr class="row2"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3546" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3546/">kryetar bashkie ---&gt; </a></th></tr>


<tr class="row1"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3545" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3545/">Rama kryetar ---&gt; </a></th></tr>


<tr class="row2"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3544" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3544/">Edi Rama ---&gt; </a></th></tr>


<tr class="row1"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3543" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3543/">miratoi Edi ---&gt; </a></th></tr>


<tr class="row2"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3542" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3542/">projektin miratoi ---&gt; </a></th></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you to all!

Comment: Your CSS is wrong. Use `.important` instead of `important` to format elements with that class attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery `each` function to read all `tr's` and if content starts with capital letter then find the `a` tag inside it then adding class `important`.

Something like this:

```js
$('#result_list > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
var t = $(this).text();
if(t.charAt(0) === t.charAt(0).toUpperCase()){
    $(this).find('a').addClass("important");
}
});
```

```css
.important{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="result_list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col"  class="action-checkbox-column">
                <div class="text"><span><input type="checkbox" id="action-toggle" /></span></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col"  class="column-__str__">
                <div class="text"><span>Bigram</span></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody style="text-align:left;">
<tr class="row1"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3641" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3641/">Ramës Mapo ---&gt; </a></th></tr>
<tr class="row2"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3640" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3640/">Edi Ramës ---&gt; </a></th></tr>
<tr class="row2"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3554" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3554/">përmbysi lulishten ---&gt; </a></th></tr>
<tr class="row1"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3553" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3553/">bredhat përmbysi ---&gt; </a></th></tr>
<tr class="row2"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3552" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3552/">preu bredhat ---&gt; </a></th></tr>
<tr class="row1"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3551" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3551/">tregon preu ---&gt; </a></th></tr>
<tr class="row2"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3550" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3550/">sheshit tregon ---&gt; </a></th></tr>
<tr class="row1"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3549" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3549/">gjelbërim sheshit ---&gt; </a></th></tr>
<tr class="row2"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3548" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3548/">Flet gjelbërim ---&gt; </a></th></tr>
<tr class="row1"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3547" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3547/">bashkie Flet ---&gt; </a></th></tr>
<tr class="row2"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3546" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3546/">kryetar bashkie ---&gt; </a></th></tr>
<tr class="row1"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3545" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3545/">Rama kryetar ---&gt; </a></th></tr>
<tr class="row2"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3544" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3544/">Edi Rama ---&gt; </a></th></tr>
<tr class="row1"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3543" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3543/">miratoi Edi ---&gt; </a></th></tr>
<tr class="row2"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3542" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3542/">projektin miratoi ---&gt; </a></th></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pure js to achieve this.

Get the `ascii` value of the first letter and check whether it is a capital letter or not.

```js
var table = document.getElementById('result_list');
var rows = table.rows;

for(i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
  var f_char = rows[i].textContent.charCodeAt(0);
  if (f_char >= 65 && f_char <= 90) {
    rows[i].classList.add("important");
  }
}
```

```css
.important {
  background-color:red
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


    <style>
important {background-color:red}'
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var t = document.getElementsByClassName("field-__str__").textContent;
        //alert(t);
        if(t.charAt(0) === t.charAt(0).toUpperCase())
        {
            $("field-__str__ tr th a").addClass("important");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="result_list">
<thead>
<tr>

<th scope="col"  class="action-checkbox-column">

   <div class="text"><span><input type="checkbox" id="action-toggle" /></span></div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</th>
<th scope="col"  class="column-__str__">

   <div class="text"><span>Bigram</span></div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>


<tr class="row1"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3641" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3641/">Ramës Mapo ---&gt; </a></th></tr>


<tr class="row2"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3640" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3640/">Edi Ramës ---&gt; </a></th></tr>

<tr class="row2"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3554" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3554/">përmbysi lulishten ---&gt; </a></th></tr>


<tr class="row1"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3553" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3553/">bredhat përmbysi ---&gt; </a></th></tr>


<tr class="row2"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3552" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3552/">preu bredhat ---&gt; </a></th></tr>


<tr class="row1"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3551" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3551/">tregon preu ---&gt; </a></th></tr>


<tr class="row2"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3550" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3550/">sheshit tregon ---&gt; </a></th></tr>


<tr class="row1"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3549" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3549/">gjelbërim sheshit ---&gt; </a></th></tr>


<tr class="row2"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3548" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3548/">Flet gjelbërim ---&gt; </a></th></tr>


<tr class="row1"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3547" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3547/">bashkie Flet ---&gt; </a></th></tr>


<tr class="row2"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3546" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3546/">kryetar bashkie ---&gt; </a></th></tr>


<tr class="row1"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3545" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3545/">Rama kryetar ---&gt; </a></th></tr>


<tr class="row2"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3544" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3544/">Edi Rama ---&gt; </a></th></tr>


<tr class="row1"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3543" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3543/">miratoi Edi ---&gt; </a></th></tr>


<tr class="row2"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3542" /></td><th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3542/">projektin miratoi ---&gt; </a></th></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing `.` at selector `$("field-__str__ tr th a").addClass("important");` , also `tr` is not child node of `.field-__str__`. Wrapped `javascript` within `.ready()` to call when `document` is loaded.

```
    $(function() {
      var t = $(".field-__str__");
      for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        var text = t.eq(i).text().trim().charAt(0);
        if (text === text.toUpperCase()) {
          t.eq(i).find("a").addClass("important");
        }
      }
    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .important {
      background-color: red
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      var t = $(".field-__str__");
      for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        var text = t.eq(i).text().trim().charAt(0);
        if (text === text.toUpperCase()) {
          t.eq(i).find("a").addClass("important");
        }
      }
    })
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="result_list">
    <thead>
      <tr>

        <th scope="col" class="action-checkbox-column">

          <div class="text"><span><input type="checkbox" id="action-toggle" /></span>
          </div>
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="column-__str__">

          <div class="text"><span>Bigram</span>
          </div>
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>


      <tr class="row1">
        <td class="action-checkbox">
          <input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3641" />
        </td>
        <th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3641/">Ramës Mapo ---&gt; </a>
        </th>
      </tr>


      <tr class="row2">
        <td class="action-checkbox">
          <input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3640" />
        </td>
        <th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3640/">Edi Ramës ---&gt; </a>
        </th>
      </tr>

      <tr class="row2">
        <td class="action-checkbox">
          <input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3554" />
        </td>
        <th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3554/">përmbysi lulishten ---&gt; </a>
        </th>
      </tr>


      <tr class="row1">
        <td class="action-checkbox">
          <input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3553" />
        </td>
        <th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3553/">bredhat përmbysi ---&gt; </a>
        </th>
      </tr>


      <tr class="row2">
        <td class="action-checkbox">
          <input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3552" />
        </td>
        <th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3552/">preu bredhat ---&gt; </a>
        </th>
      </tr>


      <tr class="row1">
        <td class="action-checkbox">
          <input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3551" />
        </td>
        <th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3551/">tregon preu ---&gt; </a>
        </th>
      </tr>


      <tr class="row2">
        <td class="action-checkbox">
          <input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3550" />
        </td>
        <th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3550/">sheshit tregon ---&gt; </a>
        </th>
      </tr>


      <tr class="row1">
        <td class="action-checkbox">
          <input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3549" />
        </td>
        <th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3549/">gjelbërim sheshit ---&gt; </a>
        </th>
      </tr>


      <tr class="row2">
        <td class="action-checkbox">
          <input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3548" />
        </td>
        <th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3548/">Flet gjelbërim ---&gt; </a>
        </th>
      </tr>


      <tr class="row1">
        <td class="action-checkbox">
          <input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3547" />
        </td>
        <th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3547/">bashkie Flet ---&gt; </a>
        </th>
      </tr>


      <tr class="row2">
        <td class="action-checkbox">
          <input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3546" />
        </td>
        <th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3546/">kryetar bashkie ---&gt; </a>
        </th>
      </tr>


      <tr class="row1">
        <td class="action-checkbox">
          <input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3545" />
        </td>
        <th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3545/">Rama kryetar ---&gt; </a>
        </th>
      </tr>


      <tr class="row2">
        <td class="action-checkbox">
          <input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3544" />
        </td>
        <th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3544/">Edi Rama ---&gt; </a>
        </th>
      </tr>


      <tr class="row1">
        <td class="action-checkbox">
          <input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3543" />
        </td>
        <th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3543/">miratoi Edi ---&gt; </a>
        </th>
      </tr>


      <tr class="row2">
        <td class="action-checkbox">
          <input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3542" />
        </td>
        <th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3542/">projektin miratoi ---&gt; </a>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Vanilla JS version:**

Here's the `<script>` snippet:

```
var t = document.querySelectorAll(".field-__str__");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(t, function(el) {
  if (el.textContent.charAt(0) === el.textContent.charAt(0).toUpperCase())
    el.classList.add("important");
});
```

And here is the `<style>` component:

```
.important {
  background-color: red
}
```

A few things to note:

- your `important` class didn't have a `.` in front of it, which is needed to specify that important is a class not an element. Thus, it has been corrected to `.important`.
- Moved your script to right before the closing body tag as that is standard practice to prevent render blocking.
- vanilla JS, so if this is the only jQuery in your code, you can save yourself and others a few bytes :).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .important {
      background-color: red
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="result_list">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" class="action-checkbox-column">
          <div class="text"><span><input type="checkbox" id="action-toggle" /></span>
          </div>
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="column-__str__">

          <div class="text"><span>Bigram</span>
          </div>
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <tr class="row1">
        <td class="action-checkbox">
          <input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3641" />
        </td>
        <th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3641/">Ramës Mapo ---&gt; </a>
        </th>
      </tr>

      <tr class="row2">
        <td class="action-checkbox">
          <input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3640" />
        </td>
        <th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3640/">Edi Ramës ---&gt; </a>
        </th>
      </tr>

      <tr class="row2">
        <td class="action-checkbox">
          <input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3554" />
        </td>
        <th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3554/">përmbysi lulishten ---&gt; </a>
        </th>
      </tr>

      <tr class="row1">
        <td class="action-checkbox">
          <input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3553" />
        </td>
        <th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3553/">bredhat përmbysi ---&gt; </a>
        </th>
      </tr>

      <tr class="row2">
        <td class="action-checkbox">
          <input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3552" />
        </td>
        <th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3552/">preu bredhat ---&gt; </a>
        </th>
      </tr>

      <tr class="row1">
        <td class="action-checkbox">
          <input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3551" />
        </td>
        <th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3551/">tregon preu ---&gt; </a>
        </th>
      </tr>

      <tr class="row2">
        <td class="action-checkbox">
          <input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3550" />
        </td>
        <th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3550/">sheshit tregon ---&gt; </a>
        </th>
      </tr>

      <tr class="row1">
        <td class="action-checkbox">
          <input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3549" />
        </td>
        <th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3549/">gjelbërim sheshit ---&gt; </a>
        </th>
      </tr>

      <tr class="row2">
        <td class="action-checkbox">
          <input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3548" />
        </td>
        <th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3548/">Flet gjelbërim ---&gt; </a>
        </th>
      </tr>

      <tr class="row1">
        <td class="action-checkbox">
          <input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3547" />
        </td>
        <th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3547/">bashkie Flet ---&gt; </a>
        </th>
      </tr>

      <tr class="row2">
        <td class="action-checkbox">
          <input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3546" />
        </td>
        <th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3546/">kryetar bashkie ---&gt; </a>
        </th>
      </tr>

      <tr class="row1">
        <td class="action-checkbox">
          <input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3545" />
        </td>
        <th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3545/">Rama kryetar ---&gt; </a>
        </th>
      </tr>

      <tr class="row2">
        <td class="action-checkbox">
          <input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3544" />
        </td>
        <th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3544/">Edi Rama ---&gt; </a>
        </th>
      </tr>

      <tr class="row1">
        <td class="action-checkbox">
          <input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3543" />
        </td>
        <th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3543/">miratoi Edi ---&gt; </a>
        </th>
      </tr>

      <tr class="row2">
        <td class="action-checkbox">
          <input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="3542" />
        </td>
        <th class="field-__str__"><a href="/admin/app/bigram/3542/">projektin miratoi ---&gt; </a>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script>
    var t = document.querySelectorAll(".field-__str__");
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(t, function(el) {
      if (el.textContent.charAt(0) === el.textContent.charAt(0).toUpperCase())
        el.classList.add("important");
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where to start.....

Your code is full of so many errors:

```
<style>
    important {background-color:red}'
    ^ no dot, so no class-selector  ^ ????
    /* Should be: */
    .important {background-color:red}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

    /* This script is called immediately, before the DOM is build. 
     * So there are no elements at this time. */

    var t = document.getElementsByClassName("field-__str__").textContent;
    /* getElementsByClassName return an array of elements, notice the plural */

    //alert(t);
    if(t.charAt(0) === t.charAt(0).toUpperCase())
    {
        /* Will add it to all a-elements, since there is nothing
         * specific in this selector */
        $("field-__str__ tr th a").addClass("important");
    }
</script>
```

Better:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Everything within $(function() { ... }); will be called
    // when the dom is ready
    $(function() {
        // For each element with class '.field__str__', do
        $('.field-__str__').each(function(index, elem) {
            var t = elem.textContent;
            if(t.charAt(0) === t.charAt(0).toUpperCase())
            {
                $(elem).find('a').addClass("important");
            }               
        });
    });
</script>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/petervanderwal/swqxx7ab/1/)